# How to create parent system with C++?

Tags: c++

I'd need to know how'd I index different type object by either their name or number (Or whatever with what I can loop trough every item in specific parent)
Or is there any other way that I could for handling massive amount of objects without doing like.

```
obj1.blah = blah
obj2.blah = blah
```

Comment: You mean like an array/vector/map (if you want a key)?

Comment: This question makes no sense without context. What are you trying to achieve? Do you know about the container library that is part of C++?

Comment: I just wanted to store different type variables to somekind of array.

Answer (score 1):

Using a map, you can make associative arrays, i.e. refer to different instances of the object via a string name.

```
#include <map>

class ObjectType {
public:
  void DoSomething()
  {
     std::cout << "Did something\n";
  };
};

std::map<std::string, ObjectType> objects;
objects["object1"] =  ObjectType();
objects["object2"] =  ObjectType();

objects["object2"].DoSomething();
...
```

Answer (score 1):

The standard way to handle many objects in C++ is to use a container, e.g. `vector`:

```
#include <vector>
#include "MyObject.hpp" // contains your object type definition

int main()
{
    std::vector<MyObject> v = populate_container_with_objects();
```

Now you can iterate over it very easily:

```
    for (auto & ob  : v)
    {
        do_something_useful_with(ob);
    }
}
```

On old compilers, you would have to say:

```
for (std::vector<MyObject>::iterator it = v.begin(), end = v.end(); it != end; ++it)
{
    do_something_useful_with(*it);
}
```